# Contiki and Python

Tags: python, contiki

I have come across [Contiki](http://www.contiki-os.org/index.html) recently and looks like a really interesting platform for many awesome projects. Contiki uses C for developing its applications. So what I want to ask about is whether Python can be used instead of C?!

Comment: Why am I getting negative votes?! I tried to search!!!

Comment: You're getting negative votes because is seems like you have no idea what you are doing. Contiki is for micro-controller based systems with a few K of memory and python is a script-based language that requires tens of megabytes.

Comment: @morty Now I get it better. Thanks, sir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @morty pointed out, Python requires a runtime to be executed.
So, as in any operating system you need a native interpreter for the bytecode.

Most python interpreters could not fit on a constrained device where Contiki would run but there is a very nice project called Python-on-a-chip
http://code.google.com/p/python-on-a-chip/

From the main page

> Welcome! Python-on-a-Chip (p14p) is a project to develop a reduced Python virtual machine (codenamed PyMite) that runs a significant subset of the Python language on microcontrollers without an OS. The other parts of p14p are the device drivers, high-level libraries and other tools.

**Be aware of what PyMite can or cannot do:**

> Features of the PyMite VM:
>
> - Requires roughly 55 KB program memory
> - Initializes in 4KB RAM; print "hello world" needs 5KB; 8KB is the minimum recommended RAM.
> - Supports integers, floats, tuples, lists, dicts, functions, modules, classes, generators, decorators and closures
> - Supports 25 of 29 keywords and 89 of 112 bytecodes from Python 2.6
> - Can run multiple stackless green threads (round-robin)
> - Has a mark-sweep garbage collector
> - Has a hosted interactive prompt for live coding
> - Licensed under the GNU GPL ver. 2
>
> The PyMite VM DOES NOT HAVE:
>
> - A built-in compiler
> - Any of Python's libraries (no batteries included)
> - A ready-to-go solution for the beginner (you need to know C and how to work with microcontrollers)

An interesting project on top of PyMite is https://github.com/tecip-nes/contiki-tres,  a programming abstraction framework for IoT-based WSNs.

Answer (score 2):

No. Python requires a runtime-environment, which will not run on any device that is a target-platform for Contiki.
There are however some Python-to-C compilers, but I doubt you'll be able to get any reasonable results without good C-knowledge to get the interfaces right.

Comment: There is https://micropython.org/ though, targeting a Cortex M4 based board, which is close-but-not-quite in the upper range of Contiki target hardware.